CookieBot w/ Consent Mode is blocking all GA Conversion Events
Hi I have implemented the Cookiebot CMP using Google Tag Manager and Google's Consent Mode. I followed the tutorial on https://support.cookiebot.com/hc/en-us/articles/360003793854-Google-Tag-Manager-deployment
My only other tag in my container besides the Cookiebot CMP tag, is the GA4 tag which fires all the time.
Prior to installing the cookebot, all our custom signup conversion events were working properly.
My settings are attached.


thanks!
